# Form with model checkbox with state problem with checking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a table and for every column i have a model and inside a form but the checkbox I get wrong output when I click it multiple time.

I want to set up default values from the table but for checkbox something i missing and you cannot used it.

The checkbox is not working correct for some clicks.

From true is go to false and then again false.

```
    var defaultValues = { 
        email: data.email, 
        first: data.first,  
        last: data.last, 
        reserve: data.reserve  == "true" ? true : false,
    }

    const [isReserve, setIsReserve] = useState( defaultValues.reserve );

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("use eeff: ",defaultValues.reserve  );
        form.setFieldsValue(defaultValues);
    }, [form, defaultValues])

    const onChangeCheck  = e => {
        setIsReserve(e.target.checked);
        console.log("clicked: ", e.target.checked);
        //defaultValues.reserve = e.target.checked;
        //form.setFieldsValue(defaultValues)
    }


     <Form.Item
         name="reserve"
         label="Is Reserve"
         valuePropName="checked"
      >
        <Checkbox onChange={onChangeCheck}></Checkbox>
      </Form.Item>
```

Logs from console:

```
clicked:  true  
use eeff:  true 

clicked:  false (here the checkbox didn't change )
use eeff:  true 

clicked:  false (use eff) is not printed
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be passing the `value` prop to the Checkbox component:

```
<Checkbox onChange={onChangeCheck} value={isReserve}></Checkbox>
```

Without knowing the implementation of `Checkbox` it's hard to explain why it behaves somethings this way, and other times differently. It can have many reasons varying from React's optimization algorithms, browser implementation and a universe of things in between,

but just pass down the value props and it should be working as expected.

Comment: i try it but the default value is not working :( i need to add them on defaultValues to work.